# Splitting a data.frame by a variable

Tags: r, dataframe

I have data from several subjects stored in a single CSV file. After importing the CSV file, I would like to split the data from each participant off into its own data.frame.

More literally, I would like to take the example data below, and create three new data.frames; one for each of the 'subject_initials' values.

[image]

How do I do this? I've thus far looked into options using the `plyr` package and `split()`, but haven't yet found a solution. I know I'm probably missing something obvious.

Comment: Note the 'EX AM PL' initials ... it's nothing more than illustrative of the problem.

Comment: Roland's comment is fair: if you go to the trouble of creating and inserting an image, why not simply paste in a section of data or, as juba did below, mock some up? (Rhetorical question.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`split` seems to be appropriate here.

If you start with the following data frame :

```
df <- data.frame(ids=c(1,1,2,2,3),x=1:5,y=letters[1:5])
```

Then you can do :

```
split(df, df$ids)
```

And you will get a list of data frames :

```
R> split(df, df$ids)
$`1`
  ids x y
1   1 1 a
2   1 2 b

$`2`
  ids x y
3   2 3 c
4   2 4 d

$`3`
  ids x y
5   3 5 e
```

Comment: How to access the values in the splitted dataframes?

Answer (score 12):

`split` is a generic. Whereas `split.default` is quite fast, `split.data.frame` gets terribly slow when the number of levels to split on increases.

The alternate (faster) solution would be to use `data.table`. I'll illustrate the difference on a bigger data here:

#### Sample data (what @Roland was referring to in his comment)

```
require(data.table)
set.seed(45)
DF <- data.frame(ids = sample(1e4, 1e6, TRUE), x = sample(letters, 1e6, TRUE), 
                  y = runif(1e6))
DT <- as.data.table(DF)
```

#### Functions + benchmarking

Note that the order of the data will be different here as split sorts by "ids". IF you want that you can first do `setkey(DT, ids)` and then run `f2`.

```
f1 <- function() split(DF, DF$ids)
f2 <- function() {
    ans <- DT[, list(list(.SD)), by=ids]$V1
    setattr(ans, 'names', unique(DT$ids)) # sets names by reference, no copy here.
}

require(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(ans1 <- f1(), ans2 <- f2(), times=10)

# Unit: milliseconds
#          expr        min         lq     median         uq       max neval
#  ans1 <- f1() 37015.9795 43994.6629 48132.3364 49086.0926 63829.592    10
#  ans2 <- f2()   332.6094   361.1902   409.2191   528.0674  1005.457    10
```

`split.data.frame` took an average of **48 seconds** wheres `data.table` took **0.41 seconds**